# set up loopback on a new server based on json files for models

Tags: android, angularjs, loopbackjs, loopback

My previous server is lost, I am developing an Android app with backend on a ubuntu server on AWS, what I am trying to do now is I need to recover the backend loopback based on the json files of the models. For example I am having this,

```
{
"name": "BikeStop",
"plural": "bikeStops",
"base": "PersistedModel",
"idInjection": true,
"options": {
  "validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {
  "geo": {
    "type": "geopoint",
    "required": true
  },
  "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": false
  }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {},
"acls": [],
"methods": {}
}
```

is it possible that I can just import this to a new lb folder, or do i have to call lb model and manually type in and set up? If there is a way to do it, how??

Comment: just copy paste your json files and create js files for them. Don't forget to define your models in your model-config.json and assign them to the current datasource

Comment: thanks Anouar, could you provide an example with the json i put above? I'd like to know the details of creating js file for it, also how do i define models in config.json?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your model in a JSON file as

**bikestop.json**

```
{
"name": "BikeStop",
"plural": "bikeStops",
"base": "PersistedModel",
"idInjection": true,
"options": {
  "validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {
  "geo": {
    "type": "geopoint",
    "required": true
  },
  "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": false
  }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {},
"acls": [],
"methods": {}
}
```

Now create a javascript file for this model as

**bikestop.js**

```
   'use strict';

    module.exports = function(Bikestop) {

    };
```

PS : Model name should has only the first letter uppercase.

Finally define this model in **model-config.json**

```
  "BikeStop": {
    "dataSource": "YourDataSourceName",
    "public": true
  }
```